# Library Depending upon integrating application for Spring Version

Tags: java, spring, maven

So I am writing a library for some features and the inner library needs to use `Spring`. I don't want to put in the version of `Spring` in the inner library. I want that the application using the library defines the version of Spring to use.

Is this even possible? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven wise, clearly your library needs to be dependent on spring because it has to be compiled somehow so at least spring annotations like `@Autowire` or `@Configuration` / `@Bean` need to be in the compilation classpath.

However in the `pom.xml` of the library you can declare the dependency on spring as "optional" (`<optional>true</optional>`)

So when maven will compile the application that has your library as a dependency won't need to "take" transitively the spring as well

You can read about optional dependencies [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html). Their example with ProjectA, ProjectB and ProjectX is relevant...

Comment: How do we do it for `<Parent/>`? Since Spring applications need the `<Parent/>` tag for handling versions of transitive dependencies\

Comment: Oh, you mean spring boot. Well, you don't have to use spring boot for the **library**. Only a spring of whatever version you like (assuming you'll depend on annotations of spring or something) as long as its optional. Even if your library uses spring boot, use only optional dependencies. The application will use spring boot as usual. BTW you don't __have__ to use parent in the application for spring boot. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency-management-custom-parent